# How to avoid keyerror when applying a function?

Tags: python

I have a function that looks at the sales quantities of each product in a transaction and returns a value based on the quantity.

I need the function to work for any number of products in a transaction; presently the maximum is 6 different products in a transaction, but I want the function to work even if that increases to say 9 products.

I defined the function to compare up to 20 products, but I get a KeyError when applying it as columns 'Product_Quantity_7' onwards do not exist.

Could someone please share a method by which I can make the function robust to any number of products in my dataset (I've attached a snapshot of my dataset as well)?

```
def trial_function(row, df):
    if row['Product_Quantity_1'] >= 6:
        return 6

    elif row['Product_Quantity_1'] >= 3:
        return 3

    elif row['Product_Quantity_2'] >= 6:
        return 6

    elif row['Product_Quantity_2'] >= 3:
        return 3

    elif row['Product_Quantity_3'] >= 6:
        return 6
    elif row['Product_Quantity_3'] >= 3:
        return 3

    elif row['Product_Quantity_4'] >= 6:
        return 6
    elif row['Product_Quantity_4'] >= 3:
        return 3

    elif row['Product_Quantity_5'] >= 6:
        return 6
    elif row['Product_Quantity_5'] >= 3:
        return 3

    elif row['Product_Quantity_6'] >= 6:
        return 6
    elif row['Product_Quantity_6'] >= 3:
        return 3

    elif row['Product_Quantity_7'] >= 6:
        return 6
    elif row['Product_Quantity_7'] >= 3:
        return 3

    elif row['Product_Quantity_8'] >= 6:
        return 6
    elif row['Product_Quantity_8'] >= 3:
        return 3

    elif row['Product_Quantity_9'] >= 6:
        return 6
    elif row['Product_Quantity_9'] >= 3:
        return 3
```

[Here's what my dataset looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C11GC.png)

Comment: Now sounds like a good time to learn how to write loops in Python. Writing twenty identical if statements is not a good use of your time.

Comment: This kind of data structure is not best practice. You should not have keys with incremental suffixes in their names. This means you actually need *lists*, not dictionaries. Consider changing your data structure.